# Autofill fields for logged-in users

Tags: 7, entities

I have a content type with several fields; one field defines a postal address. If new content is created and the user has logged in, this field should be automatically filled with the address defined in the user profile. If a guest is creating new content, he will have to fill in the address by himself.

How I can achieve this? Are there any modules?

Answer (score 1):

The [Token](http://drupal.org/project/token) module is a start, but it alone won't allow you to pre-fill the content.  By default it will provide a token for the value of every field defined in the user profile.

Comment: I assume this involves a custom node.tpl.php?

Comment: Sorry, my initial thought about how to do this was mistaken.  I was thinking it could be done with the Rules module but upon closer inspection I can't find a way to do that.